# App crashes on launching other Activity

Tags: java, android

So I created an app to calculate food costs, but when I press the button to take me to the activity that calculates the app crashes. The App would change fine until I added the methods to do the actual calculation. I'm new to this so I realize the code might be kind of messy.

Launcher Activity:

```
    package com.example.foodcostcalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class ActivityHome extends Activity {

private TextView mMainHeader;
private Button mStartCalc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_home);


    mStartCalc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calc_button);
    mStartCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent1 = new Intent(ActivityHome.this, StartCalc.class);
            if (intent1 != null) {
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home, menu);
    return true;


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

StartCalc Activity:

```
    package com.example.foodcostcalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class StartCalc extends Activity {

private Button mBackButton;
private EditText mItemName;
private EditText mItemCost;
private EditText mSellPercent;
private EditText mSellAmount;
private Button mCalculate;

String item = mItemName.getText().toString();                                    
String itcost = mItemCost.getText().toString();                                      
int cost = Integer.parseInt(itcost);   
String sellperc = mSellPercent.getText().toString();                                     
int no2 = Integer.parseInt(sellperc);   
String sellamou = mSellAmount.getText().toString();                            
int no3 = Integer.parseInt(sellamou); 

private String name1 = "Menu Item: $" + item;
private String cost1 = "Item Cost: $" + cost;
private String perc1 = "Sell Percent: %" + no2;
private String amount1 = "Sell Price: $" + no3;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_calc);

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder2.setMessage("Required Fields aren't filled!");
    builder2.setCancelable(true);




    mBackButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_button1);
    mBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent1 = new Intent(StartCalc.this, ActivityHome.class);
            if (intent1 != null) {
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        }
    });

    mItemName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_item_name);
    mItemCost = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.item_cost);
    mSellPercent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profit_percent);
    mSellAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profit_amount);

    mCalculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate_button);
    mCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mSellPercent.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                int no5 = Calculator.getPerc(cost, no3);
                String percstring = "Item Percent: %" + no5;
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartCalc.this);
                builder1.setMessage(name1 + "\n" + cost + "\n" + percstring + "\n" + amount1);
                builder1.setCancelable(true);
                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();
            } 
            else if (mSellAmount.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                int no6 = Calculator.getPerc(cost, no3);
                String amountstring = "Item Amount: $" + no6;
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartCalc.this);
                builder1.setMessage(name1 + "\n" + cost1 + "\n" + perc1 + "\n" + amountstring);
                builder1.setCancelable(true);
                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();
            }

            else {
                AlertDialog alert2 = builder2.create();
                alert2.show();
            }
        }
    }); 


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.start_calc, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Calculator Java class:

```
    package com.example.foodcostcalculator;

public class Calculator {
    private static int cost3;
    private static int percent;
    private static int amountsell;

    public static void setCost(int cd) {
        cost3 = cd;
    }

    public static int getCost() {
        return cost3;
    }

    public static void setPerc(int p) {
        percent = p;
    }

    public static void setAmount(int am) {
        amountsell = am;
    }

    public static int getPerc(int a, int b) {

        percent = (b / a) * 100;
        return percent;
    }

    public static int getAmount(int c, int e) {
        amountsell = c * e;
        return amountsell;
    }
}
```

Log:

```
    04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908): Process: com.example.foodcostcalculator, PID: 14908
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.foodcostcalculator/com.example.foodcostcalculator.StartCalc}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at com.example.foodcostcalculator.StartCalc.<init>(StartCalc.java:22)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
04-09 01:34:37.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14908):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `StartCalc` activity, the following declarations are initialised to `null` by default.

```
private Button mBackButton;
private EditText mItemName;
private EditText mItemCost;
private EditText mSellPercent;
private EditText mSellAmount;
private Button mCalculate;
```

So when you try to do :

```
String item = mItemName.getText().toString();                                    
String itcost = mItemCost.getText().toString();                                      
int cost = Integer.parseInt(itcost);   
String sellperc = mSellPercent.getText().toString();                                     
int no2 = Integer.parseInt(sellperc);   
String sellamou = mSellAmount.getText().toString();                            
int no3 = Integer.parseInt(sellamou);
```

android throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException` . Please note that the connection between the `View` components in the activity code and the layout are **established only after** you link them via the `findViewById()` method.

Write the above code after the calls to the `findviewById()` as shown below.

```
...
mItemName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_item_name);
mItemCost = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.item_cost);
mSellPercent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profit_percent);
mSellAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profit_amount);

mCalculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate_button);
item = mItemName.getText().toString();                                    
itcost = mItemCost.getText().toString();                                      
cost = Integer.parseInt(itcost);   
sellperc = mSellPercent.getText().toString();                                     
no2 = Integer.parseInt(sellperc);   
sellamou = mSellAmount.getText().toString();                            
no3 = Integer.parseInt(sellamou);
```

Comment: So I got it to be able to go to the next activity doing what you said, but now it crashes when I press calculate.

Comment: There is no error message the app just crashes. I will edit the log.

Comment: I looked at the log cat and I feel stupid, I realized I still had my variables as ints when instead they should be floats. Changing it fixed it, thank you very much.

Comment: I have another problem now the app is supposed to take either the sell percent or sell amount, so now the app is crashing because one of the fields is left empty. How do I set it to not crash on that?

Comment: Use an if statement to test if sell percent or sell amount is null. For example if sell percent is null then extract the sell amount and vice versa. Then write the appropriate code. The app is crashing because you are trying to access a null value. Access it only if it is not null. use a if statement to check for null before doing mSellPercent.getText().toString() or mSellAmount.getText().toString()

Answer (score 0):

```
String item = mItemName.getText().toString();                                    
String itcost = mItemCost.getText().toString(); 
String sellperc = mSellPercent.getText().toString();
String sellamou = mSellAmount.getText().toString();
```

`mItemName`, `mItemCost`, `mSellPercent`, and `mSellAmount` are `null`, you can't access to their's methods. Just access them after you initialize them by using `findViewById` method.
In your `StartCalc` activity, put this code:

```
String item = mItemName.getText().toString();                                    
String itcost = mItemCost.getText().toString();                                      
int cost = Integer.parseInt(itcost);   
String sellperc = mSellPercent.getText().toString();                                     
int no2 = Integer.parseInt(sellperc);   
String sellamou = mSellAmount.getText().toString();                            
int no3 = Integer.parseInt(sellamou); 

private String name1 = "Menu Item: $" + item;
private String cost1 = "Item Cost: $" + cost;
private String perc1 = "Sell Percent: %" + no2;
private String amount1 = "Sell Price: $" + no3;
```

after `mItemName`, `mItemCost`, `mSellPercent`, and `mSellAmount` are itialized:

```
mItemName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_item_name);
mItemCost = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.item_cost);
mSellPercent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profit_percent);
mSellAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profit_amount);
```

like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_calc);

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder2.setMessage("Required Fields aren't filled!");
    builder2.setCancelable(true);

    mBackButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_button1);
    mBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent1 = new Intent(StartCalc.this, ActivityHome.class);
            if (intent1 != null) {
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        }
    });

    mItemName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_item_name);
    mItemCost = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.item_cost);
    mSellPercent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profit_percent);
    mSellAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profit_amount);

    String item = mItemName.getText().toString();                                    
    String itcost = mItemCost.getText().toString();                                      
    int cost = Integer.parseInt(itcost);   
    String sellperc = mSellPercent.getText().toString();                                     
    int no2 = Integer.parseInt(sellperc);   
    String sellamou = mSellAmount.getText().toString();                            
    int no3 = Integer.parseInt(sellamou); 

    String name1 = "Menu Item: $" + item;
    String cost1 = "Item Cost: $" + cost;
    String perc1 = "Sell Percent: %" + no2;
    String amount1 = "Sell Price: $" + no3;
    mCalculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate_button);
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by this @Đăng Khoa Huỳnh

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `StartCalc` activity, when it is first instantiated, it initializes the variable `item`, `itcost`, `cost`, `sellperc` to values that depend on `mItemName`, `mItemCost`, `mSellPercent`, `mSellAmount`, which are null at this point (until `onCreate()` is called).

You can try moving these assign operations to `onCreate()`, after you assign values to `mItemName`, `mItemCost`, `mSellPercent`, `mSellAmount` to get over the exception (depending on what you are trying to do). But bear in mind that the value of `item` (and your other variables) won't change when the `mItemName` EditText gets changed. So, I think you are better assigning these values just before using them.